# What do I use recipientName and baseURL for in the embedded DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with the ability to have clients sign an embedded document (service agreement) when logging in to the web site. For example, the user clicks the link and is taken shown the agreement. After declining or signing, the user is taken back to the page.

Is this the correct API?

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

After creating the temple...

The API requests two things I am unsure how to proceed with:

- recipientName - since I will not know in advance who will be signing, how should I address this?
- baseURL - is this the page users will be directed to after signing?

  static string recipientName = "***";        // provide a recipient (signer) name
  static string baseURL = "";         // - we will retrieve this

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like part of your question got cut off...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar workflow where a new user placing an order is taken to the DocuSign signing ceremony to sign an agreement at the end of the order process.  They had to sign a single document with a half dozen editable fields.

After talking to a DocuSign technical rep, he suggested that we look at PowerForms for this scenario.  It is a much simpler API if you don't need all of the DocuSign bells and whistles.  If this may be suitable for you, take a look at the PowerForms User Guide here: https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/PowerForms_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: I would not recommend trying to use PowerForms for this scenario, the Embedded Signing that they've referenced is indeed the better way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Embedded Signing functionality is indeed the best way to implement your workflow.  To answer your questions-

With regards to what you put for `recipientName`, if you do not know the name of the user then one approach is that you simply ask for it.  Have a "Full Name" text box or some other input method, they input their name, then you can make the api call with the recipientName value correctly populated.

As for the baseUrl, look at the code comment - the value will be retrieved through the code below so you don't have to put anything in for it (it's value is assigned further below).  Each DocuSign account has a unique accountId and baseUrl and those are used in subsequent api calls.

The Embedded Signing API Walkthrough that you've referenced at:
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

...is a vert good resource for how to code up an Embedded Signing scenario, which is what the vast majority of sites that integrate with DocuSign use.